# Include list index when flattening list of matrices -- better solutions than this one?

Tags: r, purrr

I want to concatenate or flatten a list of matrices, but retain the list index as a new column in the resulting matrix. Preferably using dplyr/map.

This is my solution

```
l <- list(matrix(1:10, ncol=2, byrow=T), matrix(11:20, ncol=2, byrow=T), matrix(2:7, ncol=2, byrow=T))
melt(l) %>% 
  group_by(L1, Var1) %>% # group by list and row
  spread(Var2, value) %>%
  rename(row=Var1, list=L1, x=`1`, y=`2`)
```

It works (albeit the result needs re-ordering), but is there a more elegant/robust/efficient manner in which to do so?

Comment: `purrr::map_dfr(l, dplyr::as_data_frame, .id = "id")` ; `do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) cbind(l[[i]], rep(i, nrow(l[[i]])))))` ; the base version keeps it a matrix and executes in 20µs for the example matrix whereas the tidyverse version takes 958µs and you still need to convert back to a numeric matrix afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

@hrbrmstr's method works great and is very compact if you only want to know from which matrix the values come from. If you also want to know from which row of each matrix they come from, as in your example, you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

map_df(l, ~ {mutate(as_tibble(.), row = 1:nrow(.))}, .id = "list")
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
   matrix   V1    V2   row
   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
 1 1         1     2     1
 2 1         3     4     2
 3 1         5     6     3
 4 1         7     8     4
 5 1         9    10     5
 6 2        11    12     1
 7 2        13    14     2
 8 2        15    16     3
 9 2        17    18     4
10 2        19    20     5
11 3         2     3     1
12 3         4     5     2
13 3         6     7     3
```